# Неверное преобразование чисел в русские буквы С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, кодировка, rsa, c++14

Пишу реализацию RSA. Столкнулся с проблемой: не может расшифровать русские буквы. Пробовал разные варианты:

- `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");`
- `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`
- `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);`

Они не работают.

Конкретно проблема в функции `decrypt`. Английский текст и символы работают корректно.

```
string encrypt(const std::string& message, const std::vector<mp::cpp_int>& public_key) { 
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    mp::cpp_int n = public_key[0];
    mp::cpp_int e = public_key[1];

    std::ofstream outfile("encrypted_text.txt");  // Открываем файл для записи

    if (!outfile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Не получилось записать данные в файл." << std::endl;
        return ""; 
    }

    std::string encrypted_message;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i) {
        mp::cpp_int num = powm(static_cast<mp::cpp_int>(message[i]), e, n);
        outfile << num;
       
        // Если это не последний символ, добавляем разделитель
        if (i != message.size() - 1) {
            outfile << " ";
        }
    }
    
    outfile.close();  // Закрываем файл
    return "";
}

string decryptFromFile(const std::vector<mp::cpp_int>& private_key) { // main
    mp::cpp_int n = private_key[0];
    mp::cpp_int d = private_key[1];

    std::ifstream infile("encrypted_text.txt");  // Открываем файл для чтения

    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Не получилось открыть файл для чтения." << std::endl;
        return "";  // Можно обработать ошибку по-другому, если нужно
    }

    std::vector<mp::cpp_int> encrypted_blocks;
    mp::cpp_int num;
    while (infile >> num) {
        encrypted_blocks.push_back(num);
    }

    infile.close();  // Закрываем файл

    std::string decrypted_message;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < encrypted_blocks.size(); ++i) {
        decrypted_message += static_cast<char>(powm(encrypted_blocks[i], d, n).convert_to<int>());

        // Если это не последний блок, добавляем пробел
        if (i != encrypted_blocks.size() - 1) {
            decrypted_message += "";
        }
    }

    cout << decrypted_message;
    return "";
}

string cout_encrypted_text() {


ifstream infile("encrypted_text.txt");

if (!infile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Unable to open the file for reading." << endl;
    return "";
}

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int number;

    while (iss >> number) {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(number) << "";
    }
}

infile.close();  // Закрываем файл
return "";
}
```

Comment: Тип `char` в вашем компиляторе знаковый? Если так, то выражение `message[i]` может стать отрицательным для кириллического текста. Это может быть проблемой.

Comment: В файле русские буквы имеют отрицательное значение. также я изменил подход хранения и вывода:
 UINT16 temp;
    std::wstring decrypted_message;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < encrypted_blocks.size(); ++i) {
        decrypted_message += unsigned char(powm(encrypted_blocks[i], d, n).convert_to<int>());
        temp = (powm(encrypted_blocks[i], d, n).convert_to<int>());
        cout << (char)temp;
        // Если это не последний блок, добавляем пробел
        
    }
Все равно ошибка с русским текстом

Comment: Не нужно wstring. С точки зрения шифровки/расшифровки текст - массив байт. Прочтите русский текст, распечатайте байты для контроля, зашифруйте, расшифруйте, распечатайте байты для контроля. Если байты совпадут, уберите из вопроса шифрование. Если байты разные, уберите из вопроса русский язык.